# What is |= and divmod

Tags: python

I want to ask you how |= works.
I found this code to find all factors of number:

```
def factors(n):    
    result = set()
    for i in range(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        div, mod = divmod(n, i)
        if mod == 0:
            result |= {i, div}
    return result
```

I don't understand this (EDIT: now I know):

```
div, mod = divmod(n, i)
```

And this (I know |= is Bitwise OR but what it means?):

```
result |= {i, div}
```

Can someone teach me how it works?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you looked at the documentation for `divmod` and `set`, or even just the `help` page?

Comment: `divmod` returns two values, and those are assigned to `div` and `mod`.

Comment: `divmod(n, i)` performs integer division of n by i, and returns the result & the rest as tuple. the other line is just an in-place union of elements in `result` set.

Comment: Aside: this code will, I think, fail for sufficiently large numbers close to squares because of the error in `n ** 0.5`.

Comment: Hurkyl, I did, but I can not understand it

Comment: But the hardest is to know what |= is.

Comment: It's explained here. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: return set s with elements added from t - does it mean that if i have a={5,6,8) and b = (4,5,7) a |= b is {4,5,6,7,8}?

Comment: yes. Stored in a in place.

Answer (score 2):

divmod is function that takes two numbers as arguments and returns tuple of 2 elements there first number is the quotient and the second is remainder.(https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod)

|= is equivalent to result = result.union()
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what |= is too?

Comment: I gave you + but I have less than 15 reputation ;-)